# update seconds real time react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I have this code:

```
var Difference = new Date().getTime() - new Date('November 15, 2020').getTime();
var seconds = Math.floor(Difference / 3600) % 60;
```

I want to display the variable "seconds" in my website and update seconds in real time without refreshing the page, how can I do it?

Comment: Check out [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [states](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) in react and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) before you read the answer.

You can combine `useState` and `useEffect`, first, you will have to create a state

```js
// Assuming you are using functional components
const [time, setTime] = useState(
    // add whatever initial value suitable for you
);
```

Then you should make an effect that updates the state each second you should write something that goes as following

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // change the timer every one second
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(updateTime(time)); // use update the time according to your logic
    }, 1000);
    // a cleanup function 
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }; 
   // trigger the effect only when the timer change 
  }, [time]);
```